# Use Maven hyperjaxb3 plugin to include multiple XML schemas

Tags: hyperjaxb

I have 3 different XML schemas. I want to generate the class and ORM tables corresponding to theses 3 XSDs. I am using Maven for build.

Maven Pom configuration I am using is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
            <arg>-enableIntrospection</arg>
        </args>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
        <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
        <persistenceXml>src/main/resources/event.xml</persistenceXml>
        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc</generateDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>EventML.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <specVersion>2.2</specVersion>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <variant>jpa2</variant>
        <persistenceUnitName>event</persistenceUnitName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I want to include 2 more XSDs. How can I do that?

Comment: Doesn't an additional `include` work?

Comment: for this plugin configuration is being defined outside of execution in contra with maven-jaxb3-plugin. We can have multiple execution but not multiple configuration. Hence this is not a solution

Comment: Ahm. Why don't you move the configuration inside the execution? It's all maven things, hj3 does not require configuration outside execution. ps. I'm actually the author of hj3.

Answer (score 2):

You can just change these lines:

```
<schemaIncludes>
    <include>EventML.xsd</include>
</schemaIncludes>
```

To this:

```
<schemaIncludes>
    <include>EventML.xsd</include>
    <include>Other1.xsd</include>
    <include>Other2.xsd</include>
</schemaIncludes>
```